# how to map Outer and Inner Source to same object - auto mapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have this structure:

```
public class UserEntity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ComplexObject TimeZone { get; set; }
}

public class UserQueryResult
{
    public UserEntity User { get; set; }
    public ObjectId AccountId { get; set; }
}

public class UserDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string TimeZoneId { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
}
```

I have UserEntity to UserDto mapping like this:

```
CreateMap<UserEntity, UserDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.TimeZoneId, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<UserTimeZoneResolver>())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.AccountId, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

As you can see, there's a resolver from UserEntity to UserDto. Now, if I want to map UserQueryResult to UserDto, how could I reuse the above mapper without the need to map all properties manually?

```
CreateMap<UserQueryResult, UserDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.AccountId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AccountId.ToString()))
    .// use the UserEntity to UserDto map?
```

Comment: You'll need to introduce a IHasUser interface and use [inheritance mapping](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu how that solves the problem? I have an aggregation structure not an inheritance structure

Comment: That's why I said you need that interface.